# Andengine android titleset not display if too large

Tags: android, andengine

hello i use tileset 256 x 1344, on my tablet is ok and emulator ok, in my phone (samsung GTI 5800) tileset is too large is not display in a gray tile a place, the another tileset smaller is ok in all device.

is it a way to fix this without having to cut my Tileset and you know Tileset software to create if force? and what is the limit?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because your GTI 5800 has a different pixel density.

Put all your images in a drawable-nodpi folder (create it).

Or

Create different tile images for each density you want to support. So you have big tiles for XHDPI and smaller tiles for MDPI etc.

See: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html